# File path working in NetBeans but not in built JAR file

Tags: resources, classloader

I am trying to copy file from classpath to user specified location. However,  While running program in netbeans, file path works correctly and file gets copied but when I build a jar file and try the same, it doesnt locates source file.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("utils/mount");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
this.copyEachFile(url.getPath(), "C:\\Users\\Nikhil\\Desktop\\" + mount); //this function takes in source path of file and copies it to destination path.
```

when I trace source path I get

```
/C:/Users/Nikhil/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Aroma-Installer/build/classes/aroma/installer/utils/mount
```

in netbeans and following in jar

```
/C:/Users/Nikhil/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Aroma-Installer/dist/Aroma-Installer.jar!/aroma/installer/utils/mount
```

When I run program in netbeans, file successfully copies but while running through jar, it says source doesnt exist.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I created a function and called it as follows.

```
this.copyFileFromJar("utils/mount", "C:\\Users\\Nikhil\\Desktop\\mount");
```

Definition of function is as follows.

```
public void copyFileFromJar(String source, String destination) throws IOException{
    File dest = new File(destination);
    if(!dest.exists()){
        dest.createNewFile();
}
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try{
        in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(source); //Important step, it returns InputStream which can be manipulated as per need.
        out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Successfully copied at" + dest.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("File Writing......" + dest.getName());
    }
    finally{
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And now I am able to copy files from jar file to user specified location.
Hope this helps anybody who is looking for same kind of problem.